# Error installing the svn2git gem (EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Tags: ruby, git, svn, svn2git

I'm trying to use svn2git on a test PC before using it with my real projects.
So I have tortoiseSVN installed and a project working with SVN in a local repository (I work on my test only in local network, the PC is not connected to other item).

I installed GIT for my tests (V 1.9.5-preview20150319), and Ruby in V2.2.2 to use gem.
I followed this link :http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/08/migrating-from-subversion-to-git-with.html

but when i type the command : "gem install svn2git", it does not work, I have the following error :

`ERROR : while executing gem ... (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
The requested address is not valid in its context - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 53`

I downloaded svn2git-2.3.2 and placed it in Ruby22\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\svn2git-2.3.2

If you have any suggestion..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was also struggling with that.

You need to install a **loopback adapter** on Windows. Search for it, there's lots of guides on [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=loopback%20adapter%20windows%208) on how to do that.